# c++ WinApi register second window class error

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm Trying to create a second window on the c++ winApi and I have an error when i'm trying to register second window class. However, this classes are registered, if i'm using UnregisterClass on the first class, consequently, classes are spelled correctly.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "rgr.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100    
// GLOBAL:
HINSTANCE hInst;

HWND childWnd;
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            

WCHAR childTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  
WCHAR childWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
ATOM                RegisterChildClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK    ChildProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_RGR, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    /*UnregisterClass(szWindowClass, hInst);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_RGR, childWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);*/
    RegisterChildClass(hInstance);

    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_RGR));

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_RGR));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_RGR);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error registering MAIN class", L"ERROR", MB_OK); 
        return 0;
    }
}

ATOM RegisterChildClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{

    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = ChildProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_RGR));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = childWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error registering CHILD class", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
  CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
      return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        switch (wmId)
        {
            case IDM_OPEN:
            {
                childWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, L"Save", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CHILD , 100, 100, 100, 100, hWnd, (HMENU)107, hInst, NULL);

                if (!childWnd)
                {
                    return FALSE;
                }

                ShowWindow(childWnd, 1);
                UpdateWindow(childWnd);
                break;
            }
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(childWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ChildProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: How can you he sure that the problem is in this code rather than all the code you omitted? Cut it down to a MCVE.

Comment: You seem to be using `IDC_RGR` more often than you should. But since your code only ever registers a single window class, it doesn't match the question. Please produce a [mcve] (emphasis on **minimal**).

Comment: When you start out writing code like this, paying attention to the good error reporting is *really* important.  Because there will be a lot of errors.  Your MessageBox() call just says "It did not work", it does not say *why* it did not work.  GetLastError() is crucial.  You can limp along by putting `@err` in a debug watch expression.  You'll then easily find the real problem, putting window class names in a string resource is a pretty bad idea.  You did so for the main class name but promptly forgot to do so for the child class name.  Make them string literals instead.

Comment: Using the pseudo-variable `@err` in a debugger watch window is dangerous, because you need to **know**, when it contains valid data, and when it doesn't. If you do, it's of great help to use `@err,hr` instead, so that the error message automatically gets translated to its human-readable representation.

Comment: You gave both classes the same name.

Comment: @RaymondChen: That was the red herring I was chasing, too. Until I looked at the line just above that, which calls `UnregisterClass(szWindowClass, hInst);`. Both calls are commented out, so I don't know, what code the OP is really running. If both lines are commented in, I would assume, that a window class that has been unregistered could have it's class name re-used (as long as no windows of that window class are still alive). Am I missing something here?

Comment: @IInspectable exactly. OP said that the code worked if they unregistered the main class.

Answer (score 0):

A [Window class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632596.aspx) ...

> ... is a set of attributes that the system uses as a template to create a window.

With one exception (*lpszClassName*), all members of the [WNDCLASSEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577.aspx) structure define properties of a window of that class. The class name is used to identify the window class. This is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574.aspx):

> Registering a window class associates a window procedure, class styles, and other class attributes with a class name.

Since it serves as an ID, the class name needs to be unique throughout the process. In your code, however, you are trying to register two window classes with the same name (the string resource referenced by `IDC_RGR`). The second call fails, and [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) returns `1410: ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS ("Class already exists.")`.

This can be verified<sup>1</sup> using this minimal and complete test case:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex = { sizeof( wcex ) };
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"TestWindowClass";
    if ( !::RegisterClassExW( &wcex ) ) {
        DWORD dwError = ::GetLastError();
        return dwError;
    }
    if ( !::RegisterClassExW( &wcex ) ) {
        DWORD dwError = ::GetLastError();
        return dwError;
    }
}
```

The solution is to use a unique window class name for each window class that a process registers. Note, that there are lots more errors in your code that I didn't address (like incompatible window styles in the `CreateWindow` call, mismatching character encodings, and so on).

---

<sup>1</sup> By single-stepping through the code using a debugger.